# CheckPoint Firewall R71: Is it possible to reserve an IP for a specific MAC address on a VPN session?

Tags: vpn, firewall, checkpoint

My Checkpoint firewall is configured to allow users to open the GUI (Smart Dashboard) only if their IP is on the allowed list.
Whenever I work from home (I use the CheckPoint SNX client on an Ubuntu laptop to connect to the office VPN) - I get different IP's and so I'm unable to log into the CheckPoint GUI.
I would like to bind a specific IP to the MAC address of my Windows virtual machine where the GUI is installed and add it to the allowed IP list for the CheckPoint GUI.
How can it be configured if it's even possible?